# Python 3.6 Input output with variables

Tags: io, raspberry-pi, python-3.6

I have a question for `python 3.6`.  I am trying to make an input-output system for a raspberry pi.  I am fairly new to python and haven't found anything on this topic.
So far I have this:

```
j = input ("type a number")
n = input ("type a number")
j*n
```

The inputs work then the multiplication doesn't.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input ("type a number: "))
b = int(input ("type a number: "))
print ("a*b = ", a*b)
```

In the first example, input was not defined. It was just printing the input value. When input value was defined as the integer(int), it performed arithmetic operation and gave desired value.

Comment: please add some explanation

Comment: In the first example, input was not defined. It was just printing the input value. 
When input value was defined as the integer(int), it performed arithmetic operation and gave desired value.

I am new to Python and this is what my friend explained me.

Comment: Just did. Thank You :)